# Sending message through whatsapp

Tags: c#, api, whatsapp

I am trying to sending message through whatsapp, I am following these following steps:

- Download latest [WART](https://github.com/mgp25/WART) for getting the whatsapp password.

After I want to use Whatsapp API for .net.

But I stuck on 1st step :(

I am not able to get the password for my number. When I run the WART I am getting the following response:

```
{"status":"fail","reason":"old_version"}
```

I am following steps:

[image]

After clicking on `Request Code` button I am getting following message:

[image]

I have tried so many things and read so many articles but not found any solution.

Is there any solution for this?

OR

Is there any other way to send Bulk messages on WhatsApp from my System?

Please help!

Comment: I hope you're not planning on sending spammy "Bulk messages"...

Comment: No I am only trying only 10-15 message per day from my System.

Comment: @mason: Thanks your your reply but I have seen this link and found that is not working that is only promotional page :(

Comment: good good, just checking! The error message is suggestive that you might be using a deprecated version of the API, have you checked?

Comment: @james  But I am using latest version of wart and I also download the source code and used latest version of whatsapp api..